# What's the optimal structure for a multi-domain sentence/word graph in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm implementing abstractive summarization based on [this paper](http://www.kavita-ganesan.com/opinosis), and I'm having trouble deciding the most optimal way to implement the graph such that it can be used for multi-domain analysis.  Let's start with Twitter as an example domain.

For every tweet, each sentence would be graphed like this (ex: "@stackoverflow is a great place for getting help #graphsftw"):

```
(@stackoverflow)-[next]->(is)
-[next]->(a)
-[next]->(great)
-[next]->(place)
-[next]->(for)
-[next]->(getting)
-[next]->(help)
-[next]->(#graphsftw)
```

This would yield a graph similar to the one outlined in the paper:

[image: opiniosis graph]

To have a kind of domain layer for each word, I'm adding them to the graph like this (with properties including things like part of speech):

```
MERGE (w:Word:TwitterWord {orth: "word" }) ON CREATE SET ... ON MATCH SET ...
```

In the paper, they set a property on each word {SID:PID}, which describes the sentence id of the word (SID) and also the position of each word in the sentence (PID); so in the example sentence "@stackoverflow" would have a property of {1:1}, "is" would be {1:2}, "#graphsftw" {1:9}, etc.  Each subsequent reference to the word in another sentence would add an element to the {SID:PID} property array: [{1:x}, {n:n}].

It doesn't seem like having sentence and positional information as an array of elements contained within a property of each node is efficient, especially when dealing with multiple word-domains and sub-domains within each word layer.

For each word layer or domain like Twitter, what I want to do is get an idea of what's happening around specific domain/layer entities like mentions and hashtags; in this example, **@stackoverflow** and **#graphsftw**.

What is the most optimal way to add subdomain layers on top of, for example, a 'Twitter' layer, such that different words are directed towards specific domain-entities like #hashtags and @mentions?  I could use a separate label for each subdomain, like `:Word:TwitterWord:Stackoverflow`, but that would give my graph a ton of separate labels.

If I include the subdomain entities in a node property array, then it seems like traversal would become an issue.

Since all tweets and extracted entities like @mentions and #hashtags are being graphed as nodes/vertices prior to the word-graph step, I could have edges going from #hashtags and @mentions to words.  Or, I could have edges going from tweets to words with the entities as an edge property.  Basically, I'm looking for a structure that is the "cheapest" in terms of both storage and traversal.

Any input on how generally to structure this graph would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @supamiu Thanks for the edit.  Definitely more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also put the domains / positions on the relationships (and perhaps also add a source-id).

OTOH you can also infer that information as long as your relationships represent the original sentence.

You could then either aggregate the relationships dynamically to compute the strengths or have a separate "composite" relationship that aggregates all the others into a counter or sum.